# Git merge does not spawn editor

Tags: git, git-bash

I am using [git bash on windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io):

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.2.windows.1
```

I have put the following into my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    mergeoptions = --edit
```

with the aim of getting git to always load an editor when I do a merge so I can check the message. I have verified that `~/.gitconfig` is being read and loaded by git:

```
$ git config --list | grep "edit"
core.mergeoptions=--edit
```

However when I merge a branch into `master` it does not load the editor, and even worse, when I look at the list of commits, there are no signs that a merge even happened! The other branch has definitely merged though. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Here is the process I'm using:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -- .
git clean -fd
git merge other-branch
git push origin master
```

Comment: Likely, a [fast-forward](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html)

Comment: @user3159253 Yep I think you're right. I don't want this so I will add an option to disable it. Cheers!

Comment: There is no `core.mergeoptions` (not really important in this case since it's the non-merge fast-forward action leading to the problem, but it seems odd that several questions today have referred to this nonexistent `core.mergeoptions` configuration item).  (You can set anything you like, git does not check: set `core.artist` to `Prince` for instance, in honor of today, and it will have no effect on git.)

Comment: @torek good to know. I actually realized it wasn't doing anything just now too and deleted it in favor of `git config --global merge.edit true`

Comment: There is no `merge.edit` either.  Merge looks for `branch.$branch.mergeoptions` and obeys `$GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no`, since git 1.7.10.  There is also `merge.log` and `merge.summary` (see `builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c`) and `merge.diffstat` aka `merge.stat` (see `builtin/merge.c`), and `merge.ff`, `merge.renormalize`, and `merge.defaultToUpstream`; and of course the usual branch controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short theory: You should consider git branches as movable labels on a git commits graph (usually, a tree, but not necessarily). So if you do a merge with a branch, which already contains a commit, the current branch is pointing to, git considers that you simply wish to include all the changes of that other branch into the corrent one, so it simply moves the pointer (the current branch) to the other branch.

You can prevent such behavior by using `git merge --no-ff` but usually it only creates unnecessary, useless commits.

I'd suggest you to inspect the current state of your commits before the merge in a graphical tool ([gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) is pretty enough but there're plenty of them), to clearly understand what to be performed.

Also it's useful to look into `git reflog` output, since it logs all changes to references states.